# Python telegram bot ReplyKeyboardMarkup

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am having trouble creating a telegram bot, code snippet below:

```py
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
    from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
    
    updater = Updater(token="")
    
    def favor_keyboard(bot, update):
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        keyboard = [
                        ['/icecream'],
                        ['/coffee']
                    ]
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "regster", reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))
    
    favor_command = CommandHandler('favor', favor_keyboard)
    
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(favor_command)
    
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

I want to add some `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` buttons under `['/icecream']`.
I mean if the user tap on  [`'/icecream']` he should be delivered somewhere he can has another choices.
then the result of user's choices should be sent to an specific user.
I searched a lot and tried many solutions but I couldn't find anything .

Answer (score 0):

There are [few "conversation" examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples) in library repository. Also have a look to images with schema that explains their behavior.